# Joomla!: how to add custom field to category?

Tags: joomla, customization, joomla2.5, custom-fields

I want to create a pictured menu of articles categories, but I can't figure out how to add image field to categories.

What I need is:

- custom file field for category
- ability to handle (change size, add some text, etc...)
- easily get in view to display
- remove it with category

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: changing "categories" to "articles categories" doesn't really make the question more specific.

Comment: What could be more specific? I have 11 categories containing articles, they're linked in menu. Now I want to somehow add an image file field to category edit so I could set their images in image menu. Also i need to postprocess those images.

Answer (score 0):

There's an image field already available in  standard the category edit form. Look in the options slider.

Comment: I've seen it, but I still need postprocessing: changing image dimensions.